# Accessing the parent html page from a div

Tags: javascript, python, html, cgi

I've got a simple HTML page with a hidden field on it. I display a DIV which has a button on for the user to click - when they do that, I want to update the hidden field on the main page.

At the moment, I have this in my main HTML (in a CGI file):

```
print "<td><input type=\"hidden\" id=\"mailUpdate\"></td></tr>";
```

I have this (in a javascript module accessed by the onClick for a button in the div):

```
var updMail = document.getElementById("mailUpdate");
updMail.value = 1;
```

but when I try read this (in the same CGI file as above) with this:

```
formData = cgi.FieldStorage()
doUpd = formData.getvalue("mailUpdate")
if (doUpd == 1):
    print "Maint button - doing update"
```

'doUpd' is never getting any value.

Hope this makes sense - any ideas?

Comment: It should not matter, but close the input tag. Can you test updMail for null before setting its value? Your code looks correct, but maybe something is amiss. Firebug plugin for Firefox or Chrome developer tools is invaluable for debugging out of situations like this!

Comment: Tried closing the input tag - no difference (but well pointed out - always forget that tag, thanks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue lies in the expression `(doUpd == 1):` You are comparing doUpd, which is a string, to an integer, 1. This will always be `False`. Changing to `(doUpd == '1'):` should fix your issue.

Also, You need to add the `name` to the input so that it will come across with the form.

```
print "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"mailUpdate\" name=\"mailUpdate\"></td></tr>"
```

Comment: Well, it's a bit better as I can now print out 'doUpd' but still not getting a value (= None). Tried assigning it to "1" but still no joy...

Comment: I updated my answer to include `name` on the input tag. That should fix the value=None.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing CGI well, it looks like you are mixing server side code with client side events. A better check of the hidden value would be to add a line like the following:

```
var updMail = document.getElementById("mailUpdate");
updMail.value = 1;
alert(document.getElementById("mailUpdate").value);
```

If you are not receiving the value on the server side, it is probably because your input field is not contained within a `<form>` element and then the http message needs to be a form submission, not a simple navigation call.

Or try this to verify what value is actually there:

```
formData = cgi.FieldStorage()
doUpd = formData.getvalue("mailUpdate")
print doUpd
```

Comment: Good idea with the 'alert' - did that and the field is being updated correctly, but that is within the javascript on the client side. By the time I get back to the server side, it seems to have been lost (I already tried the 'print' and displays nothing - when I tried concat to a string, it says cannot concat string with noneType).

Comment: That is a good point you raised, that the input field is not contained within a <form>. But since the JavaScript is verifying that is fine, there must be something else. Perhaps you are using GET rather than POST on the <form>'s action attribute? Default is GET, so make sure you specify POST. Since it is a hidden field, it might not be coming across with a form-GET.